# Calculate Year Of Working Experience

Tags: formula-field

I want to calculate Year of working experience days. I have a field "year of experience from"(data type:date) and "year of experience to"(data type:date). How to calculate Total days of experience? What is the formula  for this?

Any help much appreciated.

Thank You.

Comment: What is the data type of `year of experience from` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new formula field of Number type with decimal places as 0. 
Use the following formula to calculate the No. of Days, 
(Year_of_Experience_To__c - Year_of_Experience From__c),
provided that the datatype of both the fields is **date**.

Answer (score 0):

```
Formula[Number] => (Year_Of_Experience_To__c - Year_Of_Experience_From__c)
```

Answer (score -3):

(TODAY() - DATE OF JOIN)/365.  .